# sed + how to remove character/s that start or ended on each number

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

How do I remove the `.` character(s) that start in the beginning of each number or end on each number?

Remark – `perl` one liner also good alternative for `sed`.

Example input:

```
 .23.12.44.5.
 .233.3.3.3
 23.4.5.3.2..
 ....33.2.3.45.5
 .3.3.2.....
```

Expected output:

```
 23.12.44.5
 233.3.3.3
 23.4.5.3.2
 33.2.3.45.5
 3.3.2
```

(note that the lines may end and/or begin with blanks (spaces or tabs) which should be preserved).

Comment: Is your input file really having a leading space in each line, as you posted?

Comment: Could be spaces or TAB ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the standard syntax (since the OP mentioned Solaris):

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]*\)\.*/\1/;s/\.*\([[:blank:]]*\)$/\1/'
```

On Solaris, as usual, you may need to call `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed` or `command -p sed`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
sed -e 's/^\(\s*\)\.\+/\1/;s/\.\+\s*$//' your_file
```

This will print the modified file to standard output. To write to another file, use:

```
sed -e 's/^\(\s*\)\.\+/\1/;s/\.\+\s*$//' your_file >new_file
```

To modify the file in place, use

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(\s*\)\.\+/\1/;s/\.\+\s*$//' your_file
```

**EDIT**

- Modified the regexes to account for (possible) leading or trailing whitespace.
- Modified the regexes to preserve leading whitespace as per manatwork's comment.

Comment: Note that according to the example, the leading whitespaces should be kept.

Comment: Right you are. Regexes modified.

Comment: That's GNU syntax, the OP has a /solaris tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foo
.23.12.44.5.
 .233.3.3.3
line1
 23.4.5.3.2..
 ....33.2.3.45.5
 .3.3.2.....

line2
$ sed 's/^ *\.*//;s/\.* *$//' foo
23.12.44.5
233.3.3.3
line1
23.4.5.3.2
33.2.3.45.5
3.3.2

line2
```

Comment: This only deals with spaces not TABs. It also eats leading whitespace, which is not required (see OP and manatwork's comment on my answer).